# Searching array of objects with subarrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I have an object called Topic of which model is:

```
Topic
 - title (String)
 - subTopics (Array of Topics)
 - parentTopic (Topic)
```

Sample data:

```
Chapter 0
Chapter 1
 - Topic 1.1
 - Topic 1.2
   - Topic 1.2.1
   - Topic 1.2.2
     - Topic 1.2.2.1
     - Topic 1.2.2.2
```

How can I search for the Topic "**Topic 1.2.2.2**" using a predicate?

Comment: [An NSPredicate that can recursively traverse an object graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2285467) might also be useful?

Comment: Is **Topic 1.2.2.2** the `title` of the current topic?

Comment: @nayem Not really. But 1.2.2.2 is the one I want to search for in the array containing @[ Chapter0, Chapter1 ]

Comment: what's the type of **1.2.2.2**?

Comment: @nayem it is a tltle (String). I wanted to search the object that contains title 1.2.2.2 in the given array of @[ Chapter0, Chapter1 ]

Comment: @JoshCaswell Not sure why this is the same question than the one you indicated. In my question, the subTopics can be variable in number. Wherein the other question, I think the poster was indicating just 2 levels of nodes.

Comment: Look at the answers; I think they apply. If you don't, please [edit] your question to explain why.